# Plotting weather forecast using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, openweathermap

I want to plot the temperature into a graph, showing the whole day.
The x-axis should be the hours and the y-axis °C.

I would like to use MatPlotLib for this task. But maybe there is a better solution for this. In terms of a real time update of the current temperature to compare the forecast and the current values.
I went through the tutorial, but I can't figure out, how to access these values from the forecast. I was able to receive those data sets and print them using a for loop. But as already mentioned a graphical plotting method would be great.

I tried some basic plotting using MatPlotLib and tried the tutorials.

```
from pyowm import OWM
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

API_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

owm = OWM(API_key)

obs = owm.weather_at_place('LOCATION')

fc = owm.three_hours_forecast('LOCATION')

f = fc.get_forecast()

plt.plot(f) #How do I get the temp value out of f

plt.xlabel('h')
plt.ylabel('°C')

plt.title("Temperature")

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Comment: what does `print(f)` show?

Comment: Probable something like this, can reformat to JSON. https://github.com/csparpa/pyowm/issues/181#issuecomment-293469601 You need to put that format to something that matplotlib can handle.

Answer (score 1):

I've quickly parsed the [pyOWM examples](https://pyowm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage-examples-v2/weather-api-usage-examples.html#owm-weather-api-version-2-5-usage-examples), and it looks like `pyowm` is already providing some nice syntax for the XML/JSON that is provided by openweathermap.org (see [example XML data for London](https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=London,us&mode=xml&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22)).

Simply put, the `fc.get_forecast()` line returns a forecast object which can be *iterated over* (i.e. `for weather in f:`), and which has functions to get the forecast date as a `datetime` object, and the temperature in Kelvin. You now only need to store both (e.g. in simple lists `times` and `temps`) and are ready to plot. Note the call to `fig.autofmt_xdate()` which makes the x-axis labels rotate and format nicely.

**complete code:**

```py
from pyowm import OWM
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

API_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
owm = OWM(API_key)

fc=owm.three_hours_forecast('London,GB')
f = fc.get_forecast()

times=[]
temps=[]
for weather in f:
    date=weather.get_reference_time('date')
    times.append(date)
    t_kelvin=weather.get_temperature()['temp']## get temperature in kelvin
    temps.append(t_kelvin-273.15) ## convert to celsius
    print(date,t_kelvin-273.15) ## just to show what's happening

fig,ax=plt.subplots()
ax.plot(times,temps,label='forecast')

ax.set_ylabel('°C')
ax.set_title('Temperature')
ax.legend()
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```